# Bulls & Cows in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, algorithm

I have been struggling with the LeetCode ['Bulls & Cows'](https://leetcode.com/problems/bulls-and-cows/) challenge for the last day.  I am a front-end developer in the process of learning Algorithms, and am having a hard time understanding a block of logic achieved in Java and porting it over to my JavaScript solution.

The working [Java Solution](https://leetcode.com/discuss/67031/one-pass-java-solution):

```
public String getHint(String secret, String guess) {
    int bulls = 0;
    int cows = 0;
    int[] numbers = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i<secret.length(); i++) {
        int s = Character.getNumericValue(secret.charAt(i));
        int g = Character.getNumericValue(guess.charAt(i));
        if (s == g) bulls++;
        else {
            if (numbers[s] < 0) cows++;
            if (numbers[g] > 0) cows++;
            numbers[s] ++;
            numbers[g] --;
        }
    }
    return bulls + "A" + cows + "B";
}
```

Specifically I am having a difficult time understanding the following block of functionality:

```
else {
    if (numbers[s] < 0) cows++;
    if (numbers[g] > 0) cows++;
    numbers[s] ++;
    numbers[g] --;
}
```

Here is my JS solution I have derived that is passing all (known) test cases except for `secret = 1807` and `guess = 7810`:

```
var getHint = function(secret, guess) {
  var bulls = 0;
  var cows = 0;
  var nums = [];
  var checkNums = function(num) {
    if(nums.length) {
      for (var l = 0; l < nums.length; l++) {
        if(num === nums[l]) {
          return false;
        } else {
          nums.push(num);
          cows++;

          return true;
        }
      } else {
        // /nums/ is equal to 0
        cows++;
        nums.push(num);
      }
    }
  };

  if(guess) {
    // iterate over the secret to compare it to the guess
    for (var i = 0; i < secret.length; i++) {
      // compare the related location to check for bulls
      if(secret[i] === guess[i]) {
        bulls++;
        nums.push(guess[i]);
      } else {
        // We didnt find a bull, lets check the /guess/ for cows
        for(var j = 0; j < guess.length; j++) {
          // We have a match, what should we do with it?
          if (secret[i] === guess[j]) {

              checkNums(guess[j]);

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return bulls + "A" + cows + "B";
};
```

The failed test case I get is:

```
Input:
"1807"
"7810"

Output:
"1A2B"

Expected:
"1A3B"
```

I would love to better understand how I can replicate the elegant Java solution better, as well as any ways I can make this JS solution more succinct (and working).  The more I bang my head against this, the more `for` loops and `if` blocks I wind up writing and I just know I am moving in the wrong direction.

Here is a JSBin of my solution:

http://jsbin.com/jibusa/edit?js,console

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What's wrong with the code? Are you getting an error? Incorrect results?

Comment: @MarkC. updated answer with failed test-case response from LeetCode.

Comment: Need to see what _is_ being output, and what _should_ be output.

Comment: @CPerkins sorry I had just updated the answer, and you probably missed it.  Added output to the bottom.

Comment: +1 for a properly asked question.   You show what you did and what problem you're having.   Now if only my javascript weren't so poor.

Comment: @CPerkins Thank you very much.  I have had my butt burned in the past with poorly asked questions.  Never again :)

Comment: Ah, [Mastermind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29)!  That jsbin is outputting the expected `"1A0B"`..?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the code seems correct, from the secret `11`, and guess `01` , you have one position correct, as well as one wrong... Also, from my understanding of the game, you cannot repeat numbers: `The digits must be all different`

Comment: @Kenney yeah I actually had to update because I was confused... based on my latest changes the test case for `secret = '1807'` and `guess = '7810'` is failing.  I have updated the question.

Comment: Btw, `getHint("11", "01")` returns a different result than `getHint("11", "10")`... I fiddled with adding an `else { cows++; nums.push(num) }` after your `if (nums.length)` but it's still not right. You need to do something with the number of occurrences of each guess digit...

Comment: @Kenney The rules of the game state that you cannot have duplicated values in either the `secret` nor the `guess`

Comment: That else block of code represents the logic of determining how many cows have been found and from which number that is a cow.

Comment: @Bonatti in that case, why does [the problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/bulls-and-cows/) state that it can, and gives an example?

Comment: @Kenney The one that asked the question used 2 sources, and both state different rules.[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulls_and_Cows) states that only different numbers are allowed, and [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/bulls-and-cows/) stated that they can be duplicated and not necessarily with equal sizes.

Comment: @Bonatti Ok, could be. Haven't seen the wikipedia link come by. Maybe in an edit I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a virtual copy of the Java solution. The little adjustment to the JavaScript `charCodeAt()` was to account for its discrepancy with the Java `Character.getNumericValue`.

```
function getHint(secret, guess) {
  var bulls = 0;
  var cows = 0;
  var numbers = new Array(10);
  for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
    numbers[i] = 0;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i<secret.length; i++) {
    var s = secret.charCodeAt(i) - 48;
    var g = guess.charCodeAt(i) - 48;
    if (s == g) bulls++;
    else {
      if (numbers[s] < 0) cows++;
      if (numbers[g] > 0) cows++;
      numbers[s] ++;
      numbers[g] --;
    }
  }
  return bulls + "A" + cows + "B";
}

console.log(getHint("1807","7810"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the response with a working example.  Seeing the solution ported to JS did make it click.

Answer (score 1):

`numbers[x]` represents the number of unmatched `x`s in the prefixes of the secret and the guess scanned so far. Positive numbers indicate a surplus in the secret. Negative numbers indicate a surplus in the guess.

The code block

```
if (numbers[s] < 0) cows++;
if (numbers[g] > 0) cows++;
numbers[s] ++;
numbers[g] --;
```

translates to English as follows. If `s`, the current letter in the secret, has a surplus in the guess, then it matches a previous letter in the guess, so increment the number of cows. If `g`, the current letter in the guess, has a surplus in the secret, then it matches a previous letter in the secret, so increment the number of cows. `numbers[s] ++` is very slick: it either erases a surplus letter in the guess or creates a surplus in the secret. Similarly, `numbers[g] --` either erases a surplus letter in the secret or creates one in the guess.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain.  This demystified the logic for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this?...

```
  var getHint = function(secret, guess) {
  var bulls = 0;
  var cows = 0;
  var nums = [];
  var length = 10;
  var s;
  var g;
  for (var i2=0; i2 < length; i2++) {nums[i2] = 0;}
  for (var i=0; i < secret.length; i++) {
    s = Number(String(secret).charAt(i));
    g = Number(String(guess).charAt(i));

    if(s == g)bulls++;
    else{
      if(nums[s] < 0)cows++;
      if(nums[g] > 0) cows++;
      nums[s]++;
      nums[g]--;

    }
  }
  return bulls + "A" + cows + "B";
};

console.log(getHint("1123", "0111"));
console.log(getHint("1807", "7810"));
```

Ouput:

```
"1A1B"
"1A3B"
```