# Simple bulls and cows java game

Tags: java, methods

I try to create a verry simple Bulls and Cows game (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulls_and_Cows). The game is for my school project. My knowledge is limited, so I need to make the game using only loops, IF-else constructions and other simple functions.

The written code works somewhat - generate code and understands that number is hited, but did not indicate how many cows and bulls have in the wrong assumptions.

I would be glad if someone point me in the right direction :) Thanks in advance

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BCgame{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random r= new Random();
        int number= 0;
        int trynum = 0;
        while(uniq(number= (r.nextInt(9000) + 1000)));
        String targetStr = number +"";
        boolean game = true;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        do{
            System.out.println(number);
            int bulls = 0;
            int cows = 0;
            System.out.print("Guess a number: ");
            int guess;
            guess = input.nextInt();
            if (uniq(guess)  || guess < 1000) continue;
            trynum++;
            String guessStr = guess + "";
            for(int i= 0;i < 4;i++){
                if(guessStr.charAt(i) == targetStr.charAt(i)){
                    bulls++;
                }else if(targetStr.contains(guessStr.charAt(i)+"")){
                    cows++;
                }
            }
            if(bulls == 4){
                game = false;
            }else{
                System.out.println(cows+" Cows and "+bulls+" Bulls.");
            }
        }while(game);
        System.out.println("You won after "+trynum+" guesses!");
    }

    public static boolean uniq(int num){
        String checknum = num+"";
        if(checknum.charAt(0) == checknum.charAt(1)) return false;
            else if(checknum.charAt(1) == checknum.charAt(2)) return false;
                else if(checknum.charAt(2) == checknum.charAt(3)) return false;
    return true;
    };
}
```

Comment: [There is lot of discussion in this website about this one and this is one of those](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33506698/bulls-cows-in-javascript) Please search before stating your problem

Answer (score 1):

You've already gone a long way towards the solution using the Rosetta example (http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bulls_and_cows#Java). Just continue to work through it.

Experimentation is key to learning a language well, so make sure you understand what each line is doing and test the results.

Also, learn how to use your debugging tools to see which lines are behaving differently to what you expect, and then try and understand why.

If you get stuck on a specific statement then post that. Otherwise, this question is too unspecific, especially when Rosetta has a working example for you.

Comment: In the Rosetta eaxample is used InputMismatchException. This is not in my competition, and neeto to do with simplest logic.

Comment: @VladimirDimitrow: You haven't mentioned a competition in your original post, nor is there a definition of simplest. Simple is subjective in this case as using Try / Catch and exception handling is generally considered a simple element of Java.